# CSS Display: inline overrides inner divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, inline

I have this HTML layout:

```html
<div class = "inline">
  <div class ="not-inline">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">

        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
        <div class ="not-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="isbn"> <p> ISBN </p>
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="title"> <p> Title </p>
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="author"> <p> Author </p>
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="year"><p> Year </p>
    </div>
   </div>
```

and I expected to have a searcher and a button on the same line, and then beneath them 4 radio options also on the same line, but what I get it the search bar and button are fine one the same line, but the radio options are all stacked on top ob each other, like the photo here. Why is this happening?

Cheers!

Comment: yes I am using bootstrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<p>` tags create line breaks. Remove them and it will appear on one line.

```html
<div class = "inline">
  <div class ="not-inline">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">

    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
  <div class ="not-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="isbn">ISBN
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="title">Title
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="author">Author
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="year">Year
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: or if OP wants them in tags, use <span>

Answer (score 0):

You should not use paragraph element for this because it is a block element. Block element always causes a new line.

Comment: thank you! what if I want to style the things that were previously in the paragraphs though?

Comment: You can try like this --> <input type="radio" name="option" value="isbn"> <span style="background-color: green;"> ISBN </span>.